# Variation of previous "jQuery div animate over surrounding elements"

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, clone, overlap

I'd like to expand on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590225/jquery-div-animate-over-surrounding-elements) earlier question and in particular [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590225/jquery-div-animate-over-surrounding-elements/4590354#4590354) answer which works there but not in my case.
I want to animate a div and have it overlap the surrounding div's (not displace them) and <different>the div's will have structured content</different>.

The code of the previous answer adjusted to my case is:

```
<style>
  .thumb { width:100px; height:100px;  background-color:red; margin:1em; }
</style>
<body>
  <div style="width:270px">
    <div class="thumb">
      <h2>1.2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <h2>2.2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

$(function() {
  $(".thumb").bind("mouseover", function() {
    var n = $(this).clone();
    var of = $(this).offset();
    n.css({position:'absolute', top: of.top, left: of.left, margin: 0})
      .appendTo("body")
      .animate({
        width:200,
        height:200
      });
    n.bind("mouseout", function() {
      $(this).stop(true).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

and can be tested at http://jsbin.com/ukinig/1/edit

The problem: when the mouse hovers over div.thumb, it animates ok, but if pointer hovers over the child h2, to my understanding, the event fires again, propagates to parent div.thumb again and causes the animation to repeat itself. Moving in and out of the h2 causes repetition of the animation.

I tried stopping the event from propagating from any of the children of div.thumb:
$('.thumb').find('*').bind('mouseover',function(){ return false; });

but won't work in my case because the surrounding div is covered completely by its content so the animation is never fired.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd recommend to use the latest jQuery version (which is 1.8.3) if your project allows this.

I have achieved the proper resizing with the use of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.
Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
There it says:

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior.

Your code  would look like:

```
$(function() {
  $(".thumb").on("mouseenter", function() {
    var n = $(this).clone();
    var of = $(this).offset();
    n.css({position:'absolute', top: of.top, left: of.left, margin: 0})
      .appendTo("body")
      .animate({
        width:200,
        height:200
      });

    n.on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).stop(true).remove();
    });
  });


});
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the prompt reply. Second, it worked like a charm. I was aware of the on() mechanism but didn't remember the subtle difference from bind().

Comment: Happy it worked for you. Be aware of that the on() method was introduced in jQuery 1.7 and doesn't work in versions prior to this. If you're forced to use an older jQuery version you're still able to use the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events. I would be grateful if you'd mark the answer as solution.